# mlogit error - Error - replacement has x rows, data has y. Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id1", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, :

Tags: python, r, dataframe, mlogit

I have created a data frame in Python which doesn't contain any NA values:
`print(df.empty == True)` and I got `False` as output.

When I import the data frame to R using the mlogit library:

```
library("mlogit")
X <- read.csv("/Users/abc/df.csv")
df <- mlogit.data(data=X, choice="Place", shape="long", id.var = "id.var", alt.var = "Alternative")
```

but then I got the following error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id1", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 292096 rows, data has 292099
```

Is there any way I can check what went wrong? As the data frame is too large for me to check manually. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Struggling with this myself